# bash script to control multiple services

Tags: arrays, bash, filter, associative-array

i'm trying to write a script which lets me send commands to multiple services based on the passed params.

currently i'm declaring an associative array like

```
declare -A services0=(
  [name]='service-a'
  [port]='1234'
  [type]='typa-x'
  [...]='...'
)
declare -A services1=(
  [name]='service-b'
  [port]='1234'
  [type]='typa-y'
  [...]='...'
)
declare -A services?=(...

declare -n services
```

for a single param that works fine because then i do something like

```
for services in ${!services@}; do       
    if [[ "$PARAM_TYPE" == ${services[type]} ]]; then
        do something...
    fi      
done
```

but now i want to add a bunch of new params.
my idea was to filter the associative array per param like

```
#step1 - filter associative array to objects where attribute-a is param-a if it is set
for services in ${!services@}; do   
    if [[ "$PARAM_TYPE" != ${services[type]} ]]; then
        echo "Removing ${services[name]}"
        unset -v 'services[$services]'
    fi
#step2 - filter whats left after the previous step where attribute-b is param-b if it is set
#step3 - repeat for all possible params...
#step_last - iterate over the filtered array and execute commands
```

but i'm struggling removing the objects from the associative array i want to filter as they are not getting removed. when i execute

```
echo "services: ${!services@}"
output: 'services: services0 services1 services2 ...'
```

i get the same is if i've havn't filtered at all.

also when i iterate over the array again like

```
for services in ${!services@}; do
    echo "executing commands for ${services[name]}";
done
```

i get this warning twice

```
warning: services : circular name reference
```

once for the echo line and then for the for line.

am i on the right track here? what am i missing to make this work or is this a completely wrong approach?

thanks, bernd

Comment: What is `unset -v 'services[$services]'` supposed to do? It seems to my eyes that it should have been `unset services[name]`

Comment: It'll probably work if you reDeclare whole array each time.

Comment: You'd avoid the circular reference if you didn't name the current instance `services`. For example, `for ServicesVar in "${!services@}"; do declare -n currServices="$ServicesVar"; ...; unset -n currServices; done` -- note how `ServicesVar` does not match `services*`, so `"${!services@}"` doesn't expand to it.

Comment: Personally, I'd uses `services_0`, `services_1`, etc, then `servicesVar` and `services` -- the point is to have the prefix used for the arrays not be matched by the namevar itself or anything you use to refer to the index the namevar is currently pointing into.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to unset an entire array `services3`.

But your unset line says to unset an entire array `services`.

The fact that it says to unset some subkey of this variable is irrelevant, since it is not an array. So you may as well be writing

```bash
unset 'services'
```

which will unset the for-loop variable `services`. Which will then be set again on the next iteration of the for-loop.

What you want is

```bash
unset "$services"
```

which probably would have been clearer if the variable had been named properly. `services` is never multiple services, only one at a time. Which would make this a simple issue of uninterpreted string `'service'` vs bash interpreted `"$service"` being fed to the `unset` builtin.

Comment: `unset -n` if you want to unset the namevar itself as opposed to its target.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is that an undocumented option on unset? Oh I see the gnu.org docs mention it, but no man pages have it yet.

Comment: `help unset` should show it if in you're in bash 4.3 or newer. Any chance you might be on MacOS (with its local 3.2 release)?

Comment: help unset does show it, but man unset for bash 5.1.16 does not, nor do online manpages.